Why am i getting Internal Server Error Status 500? LinkedIn API : organizationalEntityShareStatistics
UPDATE: I believe there is an issue with the endpoint. When not specifiying a specific UGC Post, I get lifetime stats for the organization returned just fine. As soon as I specify a post with the URN, i get a 500 error. Would love for someone at LinkedIn to look into this but am not getting any help when submitting support tickets. They suggest posting here
I am referencing the documentation linked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2024-09&tabs=http#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-ugc-posts
Here is my code. Screenshot of response also included. Any ideas?
Version = '202408'.
code
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics"

params = {
    "q": "organizationalEntity",
    "organizationalEntity": organization_id,
    "ugcPosts": "urn:li:ugcPost:"
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {linkedin_api_accesstoken}',
    'Linkedin-Version': version,
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
}

# Make the GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

# Check the response status code and print the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Success:", response.json())
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)


I believe there is an issue with the endpoint. When not specifiying a specific UGC Post, I get lifetime stats for the organization returned just fine. As soon as I specify a post with the URN, i get a 500 error. Would love for someone at LinkedIn to look into this but am not getting any help when submitting support tickets. They suggest posting here.

I think the documentation is out of date.
After doing some tests, it seems that you have to use List(urn1,urn2) for the ugcPosts parameter value. The urn values ​​must be encoded, but the parentheses for List must not be.
Here is an example with cURL with dummy data:
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A0123456789&ugcPosts=List(urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A0987654321)'-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' -H 'Authorization: Bearer accessToken' -H 'LinkedIn-Version: 202410'

This works for me. Thank you!
